# Equivalence between two sets when the intersection and union of a third set is equivalent

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I hope that the title isn't too confusing, basically I've become stuck trying to prove or disprove the following problem:

Given that there are three sets, I, J, and K

Such that

1. $I \cup K = J \cup K$
2. $I \cap K = J \cap K$

Will it always hold that $I = J$?

I cannot seem to find an example that would disprove this, and any attempts I make to prove it end up just complicating it. Could I get some pointers as how to approach this sort of problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do it point-wise. Suppose $x \in I$ so $x \in I \cup K=J \cup K$, then $x \in J$ or $K$. If it is in J, then we are fine. Otherwise, $x \in K$ and $I$ so $x \in I \cap K=J \cap K$. This is a contradiction since this says $x \in J$. So $I \subset J$. The same goes for $J \subset I$.

Alternatively, $I=(I \cup K) \cap I=(J \cup K) \cap I=(I \cap J) \cup (I \cap K)=(I \cap J) \cup (J \cap K)=J\cap (I \cup K)=J \cap (J \cup K)=J.$

Answer (score 1):

Every element of $I$ is either in $K$ or not. One of your statements will prove it in $J$ in each case